# Insertar datos a una tabla de MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un Login con PHP y MySQL, el problema es que no puedo registrar a un usuario en la base de datos. Si lo hago desde la misma base de datos si funciona sin problemas, pero lo que necesito es que se agregue desde PHP. Adjunto el formulario y el codigo para agregar un usuario en PHP

**Este es el fomulario que estoy utilizando**

```
<form method="POST" action="registro.php">
<div class="container">

<div class="signup-form-container">

     <!-- form start -->
     <form role="form" id="register-form" autocomplete="off">
     
     <div class="form-header">
      <h3 class="form-title"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Registrarse</h3>
                  
     <div class="pull-right">
         <h3 class="form-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></h3>
     </div>
                  
     </div>
     
     <div class="form-body">
                  
        <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
               <input name="txtNombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" autofocus="autofocus">
               </div>
               <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
          </div>
                    
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
               <input name="txtApepat" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido paterno">
               </div> 
               <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                     
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
               <input name="txtApemat" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido materno">
               </div> 
               <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                     
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
               <input name="txtNumeroCel" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de telefono">
               </div> 
               <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                     
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
               <input name="txtUsuario" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="usuario">
               </div> 
               <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                     
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
               <input name="txtPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
               </div> 
               <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                     
          </div>
                    
          <div class="row">
                    
               <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
                    <!-- Guardar -->
                    <input href="Login.php" type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-dark">

                    </div>  
                    <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                    
               </div>
                        
               <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
                    <!-- Pagina principal -->
                    <a href="Login.php" class="btn btn-danger">Pagina Principal</a>

                    </div>  
                    <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                    
               </div>
                        
         </div>
                    
                    
        </div>


        </form>
        
       </div>
```

**Este es el codigo que uso para insertar los datos del usuario**
En este codigo se supone que funciona correctamente, ya que no me muestra ningun error porque te redirige al login nuevamente, pero al revisar la base de datos, no se insertó nada

```
<?php
    include("../Conexion/cn.php");
    $nombre = $_POST['txtNombre'];
    $apepat = $POST['txtApepat'];
    $apemat = $POST['txtApemat'];
    $numCel = $POST['txtNumeroCel'];
    $usuario = $_POST['txtUsuario'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    $cmd =  $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO Usuario (id_agricultor,nombre,apepat,apemat,numeroCel, usuario, pwd) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
    $cmd->bind_param($nombre,$apepat,$apemat,$numCel,$usuario,$password);
    echo"¡Se almaceno correctamente tu informacion!";
    $cmd->execute();
    echo $cmd->error;
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    header("location: Login.php");
?>
```

Comment: Si estás usando la librería `mysqli` para conectar a base de datos, entonces te falta especificar los tipos de datos en [bind_param()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) y, además, el total de campos parece ser diferente del de valores. Si `id_agricultor` es de autoincremento, no deberías incluirlo en la lista de campos.

Comment: Por otra parte, no debes enviar contenido al navegador antes de `header()` y tú tienes un par de `echo ...`; es posible que funcione en local gracias a un búfer de PHP, pero podrías tener problemas al subirlo al servidor de producción.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te dice @Triby sobre los encabezados, veo que tu `echo"¡Se almaceno correctamente tu informacion!";` es demasiado ingenuo. Una consulta puede fallar por varios motivos: error de sintaxis, clave duplicada, no hay conexión, etc. ¿En qué parte de tu código estás controlando todos esos posibles fallos? Un programa robusto debería prever y controlar todos los posibles escenarios. Aquí, tu código se queda en el limbo, porque está ocurriendo un fallo que no has controlado al momento de programar. Fuiste demasiado *optimista* y eso es un error en programación.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

Estás enviando un total de 6 variables en tu `bind_param`.

```
$cmd->bind_param($nombre,$apepat,$apemat,$numCel,$usuario,$password);
```

Y en el `prepare` recibes 7 variables, por lo que veo no estás enviando la variable para el **id_agricultor**, si bien es posible dejarlo vacío y que mysql haga el insert con el auto increment te puede dar un error al recibir nula la variable.

```
$cmd =  $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO Usuario 
(id_agricultor,nombre,apepat,apemat,numeroCel, usuario, pwd) values 
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
```

Si tu tabla Usuario en la primary key de id_agricultor es auto increment, lo puedes dejar de la siguiente manera:

```
$cmd =  $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO Usuario 
(nombre,apepat,apemat,numeroCel, usuario, pwd) 
values (?,?,?,?,?,?);");
$cmd->bind_param($nombre,$apepat,$apemat,$numCel,$usuario,$password);
```

También en tu HMTL puedes probar esto en el botón de guardar:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"  value="Guardar" 
name="Guardar">Guardar</button>
```

También te recomiendo utilizar una estructura MVC (modelo vista controlador) en tu proyecto.

Comment: Falta especificar el tipo de dato `$cmd->bind_param('sss', $dato1, $dato2, $datoX);`